# Group by and desc duplicate name

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with Group by issue. I am working a mysql to get the last row(red color row) of the table.

This is how the example data look like:

[image]

The query that I have tried:

```
Select *,min(remain),max(Sequance) 
from ApplePen
Group by Name
Order by max(Sequance);
```

Then the result that I get is:

[image]

The results that I want is:

**( to be shown by op here. Right now we don't know. Maybe the arrows above )**

Comment: why you should obtain the result in your image   ?... show a proper data sample   not only the expected result and explain the related  logic

Comment: create a sqlfiddle so they can test it. By the way you have a non- `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` problem with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure because of colors you are using in the sample output, but I believe this is what you may need:

```
select
  a.max_id,
  a.name,
  b.use,
  a.max_remain,
  a.min_sequance,
  a.max_remain,
  a.max_sequance
from (
  select 
      name
    , max(id) as max_id
    , min(remain) as min_remain
    , max(sequance) as max_sequance
    , max(remain) as max_remain
    , min(sequance) as min_sequance
  from applepen
  group by name
  ) a
left join applepen b on 
  a.name = b.name and a.id = b.id
```

Calculating `MIN` and `MAX` column values for every `name` and then returning the `max(id)` row `use` column.

Comment: Why do you use a `left join`? You know, there will always be exactly one match.

Comment: If I was sure about the constraints I would use `inner join`. OP didn't specify it and thus I don't want to discard anything. I would rather see the problem myself instead of it going under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple  and subselect

```
  select * from ApplePen
  where (remain, sequance) in  (select min(remain), max(sequance) from ApplePen)
```

Comment: so much thank for comment scaisEdge, but by doing this it return me 0 row :)